# Drop records from a data frame if values in specific columns are present in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have 2 data frames and would like to join them in a way I keep from second df only records unique in terms of specific columns, e.g. A and B.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                    'B': [4, 5, 6],
                    'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 4, 9],
                    'B': [4, 5, 6, 9],
                    'C': [8, 8, 9, 9]})

# return df1 + df2 where columns A + B are unique
# there are two duplicates in df2: [1, 4, ...] and [2, 5, ...]


result = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 9],
                       'B': [4, 5, 6, 6, 9],
                       'C': [7, 8, 9, 9, 9]})
```

Comment: You mean columns where (A, B) is unique ? It might be ambiguous if C has not the same values for columns with same value of (A, B)

Comment: @BenjaminRio yes, A,B are keys, so unique. So in example below, even though C is different with df2, it is dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` your dataframes and `drop_duplicates` on `A` and `B` columns:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(['A', 'B']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
3  4  6  9
4  9  9  9
```

Comment: This is correct but does not answer my remark on the ambiguity of the choice of the value of the column 'C'.

Comment: @BenjaminRio. It seems the OP wants to keep the data from the first dataframe and drop duplicates from the second one.