# Replace / Append data in Speadsheet

Tags: python, pandas

I need to edit data in a spreadsheet as below-

**Replace:** if date already exists in spreadsheet;
**Append:** if date doesn't exist in spreadsheet

Sample data attached below-
Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Maybe dupe https://stackoverflow.com/q/71118432/15239951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last')
        .sort_values('Date', ignore_index=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2021-6-1', '2021-6-15'), 'price': range(15)})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2021-6-11', '2021-6-17'), 'price': range(15,22)})
df.merge(new_df, left_on='date', right_on='date', how='outer').apply(lambda x: x['price_y'] if not np.isnan(x['price_y']) else x['price_x'], axis = 1)
```

Result:

[image]